# 2D-Input to LSTM in Keras

Tags: neural-network, keras, time-series, lstm, rnn

I have following problem: I would like to feed LSTM with

> train_datagen.flow_from_directory

The input is basically a spectrogram images converted from time-series into time-frequency-domain in PNG format that has a dimension of: timestep x frequency spectrum. 1 sample = 1 PNG image in **uint8**. In my example: 3601 timesteps with 217 frequency spectrum (=features) / timestep.

The spectrogram itself is just 1D, but I think "**flow from directory**" function was hard-coded to only prepare 3D image matrix and thus the input shape was becoming , which is totally pity because there are some people who are only working with purely greyscale uint8 image, and some who are working with multispectral and hyperspectral images.

My codes are following:

```
import keras
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras import optimizers
from keras import backend as K
import tensorflow as tf

img_width, img_height = 3601,217
train_data_dir = 'sensor1/training'
validation_data_dir = 'sensor1/validation'

num_classes = 10
nb_train_samples = num_classes*70
nb_validation_samples = num_classes*20
epochs = 20
batch_size = 10
input_shape = (img_width, img_height)

model.add(LSTM(units=256, input_shape= input_shape, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(units=128, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(units=64))
model.add(Dense(128))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1. / 255)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1. / 255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size)

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size)

model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples // batch_size,
    epochs=epochs,
    callbacks=[plot_losses],
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=nb_validation_samples // batch_size)
```

And then as soon as I run the program, of course it gives an error message::

```
**ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_50_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (10, 3601, 217, 3)**
```

The message:

> expected lstm_50_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (10, 3601, 217, 3)

clearly suggests it does not agree with my definition of input shape of: (3601, 217)

Any idea to easy fix the problem?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you define the last dimension of `input_shape` as $3$? Just put your desired input dimensions accordingly and it should be fine:

```
input_shape = (img_width, img_height)
```

**Update with the full code:**

The best way would be to use `TimeseriesGenerator` instead of `ImageDataGenerator` but there seems there not `flow_from_directory` method meeting your needs. So, I think the best solution is to squeeze the last dimension of the generator output. Also, you have a `color_mode` option that allows to generate a 1-channel only tensor for grayscale images.
Full code of concerned parts:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Lambda(lambda x: x[:,:,:,0], input_shape=(*input_shape, 1)))
model.add(LSTM(units=256, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(units=128, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(units=64))
model.add(Dense(128))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])


train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    color_mode='grayscale')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    color_mode='grayscale')
```

Comment: Yes, I tried that too. Please read the last 5 sentences in my post. The new error when I define input_shape = (img_width, img_height) was "expected lstm_50_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (10, 3601, 217, 3)".

Comment: (10, 3601, 217, 3) means 10 batches, 3601 timesteps, 217 frequency spectrums, and 3 (RGB)-layers. Currently I don't need 3-RGB layers as the PNG files are saved as uint8 (greyscale). So I believe the "flow from directory" function must have converted it into 3 RGB layers.

Comment: I have read your 5 sentences. The code with `input_shape = (img_width, img_height)` runs perfectly fine on my side.

Comment: Hi, I edited my post to show the full code. Can you run my code in your Python?

Comment: Oh ok I see now with the generator. Edited the answer with code.

Comment: Ah alright. That works! Thanks. Now my question regarding your reply, you mentioned the Time-Series generator in Keras: does it work with 2D-data? Time-series is typically has a vector form, e.g. time vs amplitude. Once I converted it to spectrogram / wavelet matrix using STFT / DWT, then of course it became 2D-array (= image) in time-frequency domain.

Comment: Yes it does. In fact, when you have 2D data, this is the recommended way to go.

Comment: @user2754279 please, if you consider your question as answered, could you close it ? Thanks

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry for the stupid question: How do I close the question?

Comment: No problem, just tick the « answered » mark on the answer

Comment: Ah alright. There you go. Knowing that this works but the model overfits, now I created a new question: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/58781/how-to-use-timedistributed-fo-cnnlstm -> Time Distributed Layer, so basically CNN before the LSTM layers.

Comment: Ok, I’ll have a look